# handle onclick event in picturebox created on runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayout, tablelayoutpanel

I am working on windows form application in c#.

Firstly i created a table layout on run time and then inserted picture boxes after reading from database. Now i want to write sql query on every tablepanel cell/picturebox click.

Firstly I tried this by inserting picture box by drag and drop and i wrote query in picturebox_onclick function. But now i am creating picture box dynamically on run time.Now how i can handle onclick function of picture boxes that i created on run time.

```
private void GenerateTable(int columnCount, int rowCount)
{
   //Clear out the existing controls, we are generating a new table layout
   tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();

   //Clear out the existing row and column styles
   tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
   tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();

   //Now we will generate the table, setting up the row and column counts first
   tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = columnCount;
   tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = rowCount;

   for (int x = 0; x < columnCount; x++)
   {
      //First add a column
      tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

      for (int y = 0; y < rowCount; y++)
      {
         //Next, add a row.  Only do this when once, when creating the first column
         if (x == 0)
         {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
         }

         //Create the control, in this case we will add a button
         picturebox cmd = new picturebox();
         cmd.image = new bitmap("c:\\images\\abc.png");
         tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cmd, x, y);
      }
   }
}
```

Please suggest me simple way as i am new in development. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
PictureBox cmd = new PictureBox();
cmd.Click += cmd_Click;
```

Then have a new function to handle the click.

```
    void cmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

To perform unique actions depending on what PictureBox was clicked you may want to give the PictureBox a name you can relate to such as a row number or unique ID of the row.

```
PictureBox cmd = new PictureBox();
cmd.Click += cmd_Click;
cmd.Name = y.ToString();

    void cmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string RowID = ((PictureBox)sender).Name;
    }
```

Comment: Ssc456...Thanks for your reply...I want to ask that will cmd.click store that function and each time i will click in that image...it will call that function..?

Comment: Yes that's correct. You assign the function once and it will call it every time the image is clicked.

Comment: += is the way of assigning functions to actions in C#. cmd.Click = cmd_Click; would not work.

Comment: but all the picture boxes click event will call the same function...i want to fetch different records saved against each picture box in database..

Comment: Ok in this scenario what I would do is give your PictureBoxes unique names and perform actions on them depending on their name, see my edited answer.

Comment: i am assigning a unique tag (actually primary key of table) to each picture box in my code like this cmd.tag = unique_id;

Comment: Thanks Ssc456 i got your main idea and i will try it in my code. now i have not access to my source code and i will work on it in evening...thanks again